# i have memory Leak error in my project java web application

Tags: memory-leaks, quartz-scheduler

i have used quartz scheduler in my web application,
i think that it throws memory leak,
i have tried by closing all scheduler but is not solved yet.

```
        SchedulerFactory sf = new StdSchedulerFactory();
        sched = sf.getScheduler();
        sched.getListenerManager().addJobListener(new ListernerTrigger());
        sched.start();
        --------
        --------
      sched.shutdown();
```

can any body suggest me how to remove this ?